# ASP.NET MVC @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

Tags: asp.net-mvc

@Html.AntiForgeryToken() in asp.net MVC generate an hidden textbox like this

`<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="9VYEYXQIIGVOBcPluxTIWOHeYoRlklCBh7RztWXJUWxFbPwIok2rVpeS_i1jfxdB1_n16BCV5qH9VsBhkMdZB1Ukb5g1" />`

Is there any way to rename __RequestVerificationToken?

I’d like to rename it to something that can’t be traced back to ASP.Net MVC

Answer (score 0):

Sure. I suggest that you create a **extension method** for the Html helper (`this HtmlHelper`) with the same name with just a proper overload that you will be able to specify your custom ID. (be careful there already exists couple of the overloads, so maybe it is the best option to rename it to something like "AntiForgeryTokenCustom(string id)".

Then within this extension method you just call AntiForgeryToken intercept its html, and modify the id.

But the question is why would you like to it? Are you planning to do the the custom validation of this token? This "antiforgery" token infrastructure expect this id name ...

EDIT: If you want to customize the helper, you have also customize the action filter that handles the token. The default action filer is `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` you you have to override it. Some hints you can find here: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/10/preventing-csrf-with-ajax.aspx.

Comment: I’d like to rename it to something that can’t be traced back to ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: Ok, I understant, this will help you what I wrote in the answer. But still why do you using AntiForgeryToken() if you do not want that is it traced back? Are you writing custom handling of it? Or do you use this token for something else? In any case let me know if my answer was helpful to you. :)

Comment: Do you know any other csrf class for asp.net MVC?

Comment: I do not know any other particulay library. I suggest that you read this: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/. I could help you more if I know what is your problem.